# Phpmyadmin not storing correct decimal number

Tags: phpmyadmin, decimal

I am facing an issue with stoing decimal(10,7) numbers which are coordenates, i have a form which i use to insert data in a table, in 2 of the input fiels i have an autofill with the following code.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GetLocation);
function GetLocation(location) {
document.getElementById("latitude").value = (location.coords.latitude);
document.getElementById("longitude").value = (location.coords.longitude);}
```

the problem is that in my table the inserted value shows the INT number and all the decilmals are represented by 0's like wise 57.0000000 and the same for longitude can someone please help on this as i am startin with php.

Many thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with phpMyAdmin? You mention data being inserted into a table but nothing that shows how you are getting that data inserted. Show us the code that does the insert along with the column definitions for the database table that you are inserted the data into.

Comment: Ok sorry for that it was a php code error! Thanks for your comment!